# Getting Class from jar within a jar

Tags: java, jar, classloader

Hi all Is there any way to load class from a jar within a jar file. I am working on a Installer making form install4j. It only allows a single jar(user.jar) for Custom code Installation for providing all resources. In my case there is also some dependency on third party api(jar) files so I give it directly to instal4j it extracts it and place all contents within user.jar. So how can I execute my Class from that third party api. My current dir structure is like this -

- User dir

  - User.jar

    - mythirdparty.jar

I want to load class from my thirdparty jar file. Any suggestions how to accomplish this ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/jarclassloader.html refer this and http://www.wikihow.com/Extract-a-JAR-File

Comment: @DeepanshuBedi thanks for ur reply bt I cant extract it in outer jar as inner jar is signed jar if I extract it then it will lose all authentication therefor I want to load class directly from inside jar using a classLoader or something like that

Comment: Thanks for Ur efforts

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
File file  = new File("c:\\User dir\\User.jar\\mythirdparty.jar");

     URL url = file.toURL();  
     URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};
     ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

     Class cls = cl.loadClass("com.mypackage.myclass");
```

Comment: I tried this but nor working..:( still getting ClassNotfound Exception

Comment: The class-path error. if have to dig more i guess. i wouold delete this answer then.